# Natural deduction sequents: $(\lnot)$ introduction and elimination

Tags: logic, proof-theory, natural-deduction, sequent-calculus

## Preamble:

I am reading through "Mathematical Logic by Ian Chiswell & Wilfred Hodges"([amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0199215626), and [publisher](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/mathematical-logic-9780199215621))

For context I am reading through this for self-study, so I don't have the normal support of a classroom environment - and the lack of exercise solutions makes it hard to check my understanding.

I also realised that in my previous two questions I referred to this as 'sequents' and 'sequent calculus', but from my understanding now this is specifically 'natural deduction' - which appears to be a simplified sequent calculus.

## Natural deduction rules:

I am on pages 24-26 of Mathematical logic, covering section 2.6 "Arguments using 'not'"

We are giving the intro and elim rules as follows

#### Natural deduction rule ($\lnot$E)

If

$$\begin{array}{lr}
D & D' \\
\phi & (\lnot\phi) \\
\end{array}
$$

are derivations of $\phi$ and $(\lnot\phi$) respectively, then

\begin{align}
D \quad D' \quad \quad \quad \\
\cfrac{\phi \quad (\lnot\phi)}{\bot} (\lnot E)
\end{align}

Is a derivation of $\bot$.
Its undischarged assumptions are those of D together with those of D'.

#### Natural deduction rule ($\lnot$I)

suppose

$$\begin{array}{l}
D \\
\bot \\
\end{array}
$$

is a derivation of $\bot$, and $\phi$ is a statement.
Then the following is a derivation of $(\lnot\phi)$.

\begin{align}
\require{cancel}
\cancel{\phi} \qquad \quad \\
D \qquad \quad \\
\cfrac{\bot}{
(\lnot\phi)
} (\lnot I)
\end{align}

Its undischarged assumptions are those of D, except possibly $\phi$.

## Problem:

Example 2.7.1 (page 25) shows

\begin{align}
\require{cancel}
\cfrac{
\cancel{\phi} (2) \qquad  \cancel{(\lnot\phi)}(1)
}{
(1)\cfrac{
\bot
}{
(2)\cfrac{
(\lnot(\lnot\phi))
} {
(\phi \rightarrow (\lnot (\lnot \phi)))
} (\rightarrow I)
} (\lnot I)
}
(\lnot E)
\end{align}

## Questions

A) From our deduction rule for $(\lnot I)$ I can see that $(\lnot \phi)$ cancels the assumption $\phi$, so here I think our $(\lnot I)$(1) resulting in $(\lnot(\lnot\phi))$ is therefore cancelling $(\lnot\phi)$, is this correct?

B) the application of $(\lnot I)$ (1) also looks like it is taking two steps, and I cannot see how this matches our natural deduction rule for  $(\lnot I)$

It looks like it is being applied twice to get from $\bot$ to $(\lnot(\lnot\phi))$
whereas the natural deduction rule when specified goes from $\bot$ to $(\lnot\phi)$.

Is $(\lnot I)$ being implicitly applied twice here?

It $(\lnot I)$ always applied twice?

If this is the case, then my issue is that if we instead apply it once, we can generate
what I consider to be a garbage sequent: $(\lnot\phi) \vdash (\phi \rightarrow (\lnot\phi))$

\begin{align}
\require{cancel}
\cfrac{
\cancel{\phi} (2) \qquad  (\lnot\phi)
}{
(1)\cfrac{
  \bot
  }{
  (2)\cfrac{
    (\lnot\phi)
    } {
    (\phi \rightarrow (\lnot \phi))
    } (\rightarrow I)
  } (\lnot I)
}
(\lnot E)
\end{align}

I naively suspect we could use $(\lnot I)$ to create even more garbage rules, but I am unsure.

The coverage of this topic in the book isn't very helpful.

Comment: To (A) : **Yes**.

Comment: To (B) : ??? The application of ($\lnot$I) discharge the assumption "labelled" (1), i.e. $\lnot \phi$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA every other rule so far has taken the thing on the top and performed an operation on it, so I was reading $(\lnot I)$ as 'taking' the $\bot$ as input to make $(\lnot\phi)$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA however if instead $(\lnot I)$ must always operate on $\bot$ and it adds a $\lnot$ to any assumption it crosses - then that makes more sense. Is this correct?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA ohh of course, the top for $(\lnot I)$ is the *value* $\bot$ rather than a variable like $\phi$, so of course it is special.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA thank you very much, once again - I was completely stuck on this part for a few days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to consider that $\phi$ is not a propositional letter $p_i$, but a *metavariable* that denotes a "generic" formula [see page 33].

In a nutshell, the rule "adds" a $¬$ occurrence to the assumption $\phi$, deriving $¬ \phi$, and discharge the assumption.

If the assumption is e.g. $¬¬¬ \psi$, then the conlcusion will be : $¬¬¬¬ \psi$, with one more occurrence of $¬$.

In the example, the application of (¬I) discharge the assumption "labelled" (1), i.e. $¬ \phi$, deriving $¬¬ \phi$.

Comment: Thank you for putting this in answer form, once again you hit the nail on the head. In hindsight I can't see how I ever thought otherwise, this makes sense now :)